# Legacy spring boot project with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and spring-tx in pom.xml and transactions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-transactions

I'm using a legacy Spring Boot project that has the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency listed in its pom.xml also the spring-tx dependency (for transaction management), like the @EnableTransactionManagement management annotations and such.

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

My question is - is this dependency redundant? does not spring-boot-starter-data-jpa manage the transactions for you by default such that the annotations and this extra "spring-tx" dependency is pointless?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is pointless if you don't want to explicitly declare what version spring-tx to use with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.

The only case where you want to explicitly declare a transitive dependency is because other dependencies depend on that transitive dependency version.

Example:

A -> B -> C

D -> C

Dependency A requires B requires C however dependency D also requires C. But because the shortest path to import dependency C is dependency D, it will import the version from dependency D. If this import has a lower version and isn't compatible with dependency A because it needs a different version, then an error will occur. That's when you need to declare the dependency explicitly with the version in which both dependencies will be satisfied.